# Why won't my images align horizontally? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: html, css

No matter what tips I google, I still can't find the proper codes to align my images horizontally. How can I fix this? What am I doing wrong? Please help. I'd really appreciate it. Would really like to get better with coding.

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="entry">
    <a target="_blank" href="toyapage.html">
        <img src="img/mypage.jpg" width="400" height="300" />         
    </a>
</div>

<div class="entry">
    <a target="_blank" href="sister.html">
        <img src="img/secondpage.jpg" width="400" height="300"/>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="entry">
    <a target="_blank" href="Welcome.html">
        <img src="img/Welcome.jpg" width="400" height="300"  />
    </a>
</div>

<div class="entry">
    <a target="_blank" href="images.html">
        <img src="Marc.jpg" width="400" height="300" />
    </a>
</div>

<div class="entry">
    <a target="_blank" href="Cooking.html">
        <img src="screenshot.png" width="400" height="300" />
    </a>
</div>

<div class="entry">
    <a target="_blank" href="Layout.html">
        <img src="screenshot.jpg" width="400" height="300" />
    </a>
</div>

<div class="entry">
    <a target="_blank" href="carbs.html#">
        <img src="carbscreenshot.jpg" width="400"   height="300" />
    </a>
</div>

<div class="entry">
    <a target="_blank" href="photo.html">
        <img src="img/screenshot22.jpg" width="400" height="300" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
.entry {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 0;

    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.entry img {
    width: 400px;
    display: inline;
    margin: 10px;
    margin-left: 200px;
}
```

Comment: This one could really use a running snippet or fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

your images are in DIVs. DIVs are block elements, which by default have a width of 100% (= full window/vieport width).

Try to change this rule:

```
.entry {
        width: 1000px;
        margin: 0;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        padding: 0;
}
```

to

```
.entry {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

or to

```
.entry {
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      float: left;
    }
```

and remove `display: inline;` from the `.entry img` rule. Images are inline-block elements by default, so this rule is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could align your images in a table element in tds on the same tr?

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td>
           <div/>
           <!--Should be on the same row as the other div...-->
       </td>
       <td>
           <div/>
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Layout using table tags is widely considered to be obsolete, and even if one were to use table-styled divs it's not really the tool for this job.

Comment: @Maximillian is right. Using tables for anything other than tabular data is highly discouraged today. Tables were commonly used for layout when powerful `div` elements and CSS weren't fully adopted. It's better to keep your HTML simple by using `div` elements and encapsulate layout details in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting your css for entry.

```
.entry {
        width: 400px; 
        margin: 0;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        padding: 0;
        position: relative;
        float:left;
}
```

Floating your image containers to the left would be one way. I adjusted the width because 1000px would not fit side by side on most screens.

Comment: Thank you! your code worked :) its displaying horizontally, but not centered right. My last image looks smashed onto the side of the page. I was thinking of changing the size of the images to see if that might help

Comment: Using the code youve provided. I would suggest placing all entries in a parent div container.  Set the width of the container. Set margin to auto. There are many wad to center content on a page. Knowing more about the layout would be useful, but this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your images are displaying vertically because they are each nested inside a `div` tag (not necessarily a bad layout). A `div` tag is a **block** element, so there will be newlines between your images.

**Solution:** You can use CSS to force the `div` elements to display as inline elements. Try adding this CSS property:

```
.entry {
    display: inline;
}
```

If that doesn't work, experiment with other types of `display` values (e.g. `inline-block`).

P.S. You will find this w3schools article helpful that discusses block vs. inline elements and the `display` property: [CSS Layout - The display Property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp)